# Drools : Firing Rules using a Session vs WorkingMemory

Tags: drools, rule-engine

What is the difference in between these two in Drools ??
Means taht we can fire the rules based on the

**Creating the WorkingMemory from the loaded Rules RulesBase  and firing rules as shown below :**

```
WorkingMemory  workingmemory = rulebase.newWorkingMemory();
workingmemory.fireAllRules();
```

**vs**

**Using a Session (Stateful . Stateless )  to  fire the rules  as shown**

```
KnowledgeBase knowledgebase = createKnowledgeBase();
StatefulKnowledgeSession session = knowledgebase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
session.insert(Object);
session.fireRules();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use KnowledgeBAse and *KnowledgeSession, of knowledge-api-*.jar. RuleBase and WorkingMemory are the legacy interfaces and will be removed in the future.