# sessionObject.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup().setFocus() UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: drools

My drool is working fine when I don't have agenda group but if I set focus i'm getting the following error:

```
package drools;

import droolsexec.Message;
import droolsexec.Customer;


rule "Good Bye"
agenda-group "group1"
  dialect "java"

when


 message: Message( status =="GOODBYE" )
 customer: Customer(name == "NEHA")

then
  System.out.println( message.getStatus()); 
end
```

This is my rule and i'm executing it by:

```
public class ExecuteDrools {

private static PackageBuilder pbuilder = new PackageBuilder();
private static StatefulSession sessionObject;   
private static RuleBase rbase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();

public  void runDrools(ArrayList list){

    initialiseDrools();
    initiliseMessageObject(list);
    runRules();     

}



private  void initialiseDrools() {


    //1. Read the DRL File and add to package builder
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ExecuteDrools.class.getResourceAsStream("/HelloWorld.drl"));

        pbuilder.addPackageFromDrl(reader);
    } catch (DroolsParserException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExecuteDrools.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExecuteDrools.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //2. Check for any errors
    PackageBuilderErrors errors = pbuilder.getErrors(); 
    if (errors.getErrors().length > 0) {
        System.out.println("Some errors exists in packageBuilder");
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.getErrors().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(errors.getErrors()[i]);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
    }
    //3. Add package to rule base
    try {
        rbase.addPackage(pbuilder.getPackage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }


}

private   void initiliseMessageObject(ArrayList list) {
    sessionObject = rbase.newStatefulSession();
    Iterator itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        sessionObject.insert(itr.next());
    }
}


private  void runRules() {
    sessionObject.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("group2").setFocus(); 
    sessionObject.fireAllRules();
}
```

}

I'm getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at org.drools.common.BinaryHeapQueueAgendaGroup.setFocus(BinaryHeapQueueAgendaGroup.java:156)
>       at droolsexec.ExecuteDrools.runRules(ExecuteDrools.java:83)
>       at droolsexec.ExecuteDrools.runDrools(ExecuteDrools.java:36)
>       at droolsexec.MainClass.executeRules(MainClass.java:23)
>       at droolsexec.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:9)

Comment: which version of drools are you using? Did you notice that in your sample rule you are using agenda-group "group1" and then, in your code, you are activating agenda-group "group2"?

Comment: Iam using drools 5.1 .even if i activate group1 iam getting the same error

Comment: I used KnowledgeBuilder and now my code is working

Comment: to elaborate what @user2930538 said, use `KnowledgeBase` instead of `RuleBase`.  As stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205104/drools-firing-rules-using-a-session-vs-workingmemory, `RuleBase` is deprecated and will be unsupported in future versions of Drools.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have an agenda group group2 in your drl file... you have it named group 1